# How can I check if a View exists in a Database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures, view

I have some SQL code that needs to be executed if a certain View exists in a database. How would I go about checking if the View exists?

EDIT: The DBMS being used is Microsoft SQL Server

Answer (score 189, accepted):

FOR SQL SERVER

```
IF EXISTS(select * FROM sys.views where name = '')
```

Comment: You probably want to join in `sys.schema` here, as well.

Comment: Error -Invalid object name 'sys.views'. I was querying master DB

Comment: If you found this to decide between a CREATE and ALTER for a view (as I did), this doesn't work for VIEWs - you have to DROP the VIEW* and then CREATE it. The IF EXISTS still works fine for DROPing the VIEW tho, so thanks! :)

* Don't forget about any permissions when you do. ;)

Comment: Try this.  if it doesn't exist create the view (just a stub) and then alter that stub to put your updates in.  That way you never have to drop it. 
http://structuredsight.com/2014/03/12/non-failing-scripts/

Comment: Presumably one should put the name of the view being checked in the quotes? Otherwise this will never work :)

Answer (score 163):

There are already many ways specified above but one of my favourite is missing..

```
GO
IF OBJECT_ID('nView', 'V') IS NOT NULL
    DROP VIEW nView;
GO
```

WHERE `nView` is the name of view

**UPDATE 2017-03-25:** as @hanesjw suggested to drop a Store Procedure use `P` instead of `V` as the second argument of `OBJECT_ID`

```
GO
IF OBJECT_ID( 'nProcedure', 'P' ) IS NOT NULL 
    DROP PROCEDURE dbo.sprocName; 
GO
```

Comment: I like this one. You can use 'u' for tables as well.

Comment: Or 'P' for stored procedures. 

IF OBJECT_ID ( 'dbo.sprocName', 'P' ) IS NOT NULL 
    DROP PROCEDURE dbo.sprocName;
GO

Comment: I don't know if this was the best answer in 2009, but it seem to be in 2016 (though SQL Server 2016 is introducing an even better option).

Comment: OBJECT_ID doc https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190328.aspx
- and this one gives you all the object types : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190324.aspx

Answer (score 60):

This is the most portable, least intrusive way:

```
select
    count(*)
from
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS
where
    table_name = 'MyView'
    and table_schema = 'MySchema'
```

Edit: This does work on SQL Server, and it doesn't require you joining to `sys.schemas` to get the schema of the view. This is less important if everything is `dbo`, but if you're making good use of schemas, then you should keep that in mind.

Each RDBMS has their own little way of checking metadata like this, but `information_schema` is actually ANSI, and I think Oracle and apparently SQLite are the only ones that don't support it in some fashion.

Comment: Using sqlite: SQL error: no such table: INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS

Comment: @lutz: +1, for lack of support on SQLite.

Answer (score 18):

```
if exists (SELECT * FROM sys.views WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[MyTable]') )
```

Comment: For Microsoft SQL Server, I find this the most useful because IF EXISTS is often used when creating schema management scripts. In the script you probably already have the CREATE ViEW [dbo].[MyView] and the above is this simplest snippet for copy and paste.

Answer (score 17):

For people checking the existence to drop `View` use this

From `SQL Server 2016 CTP3` you can use new *DIE*  statements instead of big `IF` wrappers

syntax

> DROP VIEW [ IF EXISTS ] [ schema_name . ] view_name [ ...,n ] [ ; ]

Query :

```
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS view_name
```

More info [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlserverstorageengine/archive/2015/11/03/drop-if-exists-new-thing-in-sql-server-2016.aspx)

Answer (score 6):

You can check the availability of the view in various ways

FOR SQL SERVER

use **sys.objects**

```
IF EXISTS(
   SELECT 1
   FROM   sys.objects
   WHERE  OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID('[schemaName].[ViewName]')
          AND Type_Desc = 'VIEW'
)
BEGIN
    PRINT 'View Exists'
END
```

use **sysobjects**

```
IF NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM   sysobjects
   WHERE  NAME = '[schemaName].[ViewName]'
          AND xtype = 'V'
)
BEGIN
    PRINT 'View Exists'
END
```

use **sys.views**

```
IF EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM sys.views
   WHERE OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID(N'[schemaName].[ViewName]')
)
BEGIN
    PRINT 'View Exists'
END
```

use **INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS**

```
IF EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS
   WHERE  table_name = 'ViewName'
          AND table_schema = 'schemaName'
)
BEGIN
    PRINT 'View Exists'
END
```

use **OBJECT_ID**

```
IF EXISTS(
   SELECT OBJECT_ID('ViewName', 'V')
)
BEGIN
    PRINT 'View Exists'
END
```

use **sys.sql_modules**

```
IF EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM   sys.sql_modules
   WHERE  OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID('[schemaName].[ViewName]')
)
BEGIN
   PRINT 'View Exists'
END
```

Answer (score 1):

if it's Oracle you would use the "all_views" table.

It really depends on your dbms.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check the validity and consistency of all the existing views you can use the following query

```
declare @viewName sysname
declare @cmd sysname
DECLARE check_cursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT cast('['+SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id)+'].['+name+']' as sysname) AS viewname
FROM sys.views

OPEN check_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM check_cursor 
INTO @viewName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

set @cmd='select * from '+@viewName
begin try
exec (@cmd)
end try
begin catch
print 'Error: The view '+@viewName+' is corrupted .'
end catch
FETCH NEXT FROM check_cursor 
INTO @viewName
END 
CLOSE check_cursor;
DEALLOCATE check_cursor;
```

Answer (score 1):

IN SQL Server ,

```
declare @ViewName nvarchar(20)='ViewNameExample'

if exists(SELECT 1 from sys.objects where object_Id=object_Id(@ViewName) and Type_Desc='VIEW')
begin
    -- Your SQL Code goes here ...

end
```

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Kevin's answer.

```
    private bool CustomViewExists(string viewName)
    {
        using (SalesPad.Data.DataConnection dc = yourconnection)
        {
            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(String.Format(@"IF EXISTS(select * FROM sys.views where name = '{0}')
                Select 1
            else
                Select 0", viewName));
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            return Convert.ToBoolean(dc.ExecuteScalar(cmd));
        }
    }
```