# Searching for a view or any object in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I need to find a view in SQL Server 2000, 2005 and 2008. Actually, I'd like to be able to find anything using a simple query. I tried one answer which did not work - [How can I check if a View exists in a Database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306009/how-can-i-check-if-a-view-exists-in-a-database)

Is there a script to search for views or any other object that is guaranteed to work in all SQL Server versions I mentioned? I prefer something which does not need you to know table names and such to find a view.

Comment: If you are using `SQL Server Management Studio` you can simple press F6 and use the searching engine.

Comment: Why did i get -1 for this question ?

Comment: @gotqn - What does F6 do ? If I know, I can manually go to that menu. f6 does nothing for me.

Comment: It should open your `Object Explorer` - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174205.aspx and using it you can search for your view - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173849.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need SQL Server 2000 compatibility (so `sys.views` is not available) you can query `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS`

For other types of objects the SQL Server 2000 view `sysobjects` is still available in later versions for backward compatibility reasons.

Answer (score 2):

you may need this query

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME as ViewName,
VIEW_DEFINITION as ViewDefinition
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Views
```